# Did the First Order attack Coruscant?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

About halfway through *The Force Awakens*, the First Order destroys a planet with the Starkiller base, and General Hux says something to the effect of it being the seat of the Republic. In the brief shot we got of people on the planet, the buildings kind of looked like those found on Coruscant in the prequel trilogies. Naturally, I assumed it was Coruscant, but my friend thought it was some planet that we'd never seen before.

I know that in Legends Continuity, the Republic had their seat of power on Coruscant (same as the pre-Empire Republic), but it's not clear if that carried over into Disney continuity or not. So did the First Order destroy Coruscant? Or was it some other planet?

Comment: Spoilers la la la la, -1... JK ;P